# More efficient way of solving this example?

Tags: python, performance

I'm learning Python from [LearnPython.org](http://www.learnpython.org/) and came upon this example:

> Q: Print an alphabetically sorted list of all functions in the re
>   module, which contain the word find.

Output should look like: `['findall', 'finditer']`

Here's what I came up with:

```
import re
function_list = []
for function_name in dir(re):
    if "find" in function_name:
        function_list.append(function_name)
print function_list
```

Is there a more effective/efficient way of solving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import re
function_list = [f for f in dir(re) if 'find' in f] # faster than using list.append
function_list.sort() # faster than using sorted. This can actually be excluded, since `dir` returns a sorted list
```

List comprehensions are usually faster than appending to a list. Though I'm not sure exactly why (I'd love for someone to chime in here), I have a feeling that this might be because it allows the interpreter to allocate beforehand; whereas using `list.append` could potentially put the interpreter in a state where it has to copy all over the list into a new location in memory. This is because python lists are implemented as dynamic arrays in C, which need a contiguous block of memory.

Further, you may be inclined to use `sorted`, which uses the same algorithm as `list.sort`, but with one very important difference. `list.sort` is in-place (i.e. modifies the list itself), whereas `sorted` creates and returns a new list. The advantage of using an in-place operation here is that you end up saving the time that would otherwise be used in copying items to create the new list.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very helpful to have code snippets like this to learn from

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print re.findall('([^,]*find[^,]+)', ','.join(dir(re)))
```

Comment: I think that there is a certain elegance to using a module to find out more about a module - but then again that ***IS*** python.